# Adding synchronous call to nodejs require with least modifications

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a quite big project and I required my config files. I want to be able to change the config files on the fly, since they are read rarely and when special conditions apply. Since `node.js` caches the `require` modules I cannot really do this.

Adding a callback to the require call is not working since that would make me change serious amount of code. How should I delete the module from cache properly? I mean where should I put `delete require.cache[require.resolve('./gameConstants.js')]`? Because I am requiring modules that require the `gameConstants`. Should I add the `delete ...` command in each function that uses the required `gameConstants`?

Or is there an `npm` module that loads configuration files synchronously and does not cache the result?

Comment: Have you thought about https://github.com/remy/nodemon It restarts the complete application if it detects a change in the watched files/folders, but that's probably not exactly your Use Case...

Comment: Yes, I need to maintain my current state of the application. But it's an interesting module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) might be what you're looking for. To quote the documentation:

> The runtime.json file contains configuration changes made at runtime either manually, or by the application setting a configuration value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. If I use the `runtime.json` it has the required effect.